# Matching a voice assistant wakeword using tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, voice-recognition, mfcc

I am building a personal voice assistant for my family in Python, using Raspberry Pi units placed throughout the house plus a central server.

The Pis cycle 16khz audio from `arecord` through a ring buffer, maintaining two second window. A personal model from snowboy.kitt.ai, set very permissively, tests the window and sends matching clips to the central server.

There, the clip is transformed to MFCC using `librosa`, and a Tensorflow-based (tflearn, really) DNN checks acts a secondary filter. Every new clip is saved to a queue so I can run through and tag them later before re-training the model.

It's sort of working, but not well enough - my wife would tell you that it *loves* to wake up when she opens the compost bucket for instance. Loud noises often confuse it, even though there are plenty of random bangs and slams in the training data.

Regarding code, the starting point came from this YouTube video (don't laugh, I found it helpful!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9FPqkuoEJ8

After simplifying the example code and making some changes to reduce the number of epochs to converge, I ended up with this:

```
def build_model(categories):
    import tflearn
    tflearn.init_graph(num_cores=16, gpu_memory_fraction=0.5)

    net = tflearn.input_data([None, WIDTH, HEIGHT])
    net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(categories), activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    return tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
```

Which I train like this:

```
model.fit(inputs, targets, shuffle=True, n_epoch=10, validation_set=0.2, show_metric=True, run_id=run_id)
```

The input data breakdown is this:

```
   3 cal.wav
2950 false_positive.wav
7182 guess_negative.wav
  16 guess_positive.wav
   1 heather.wav
  30 jennie.wav
   1 jim.wav
   4 leo.wav
  40 simon.wav
  14 teddy.wav
1098 wade.wav
```

Wake word (yes/no) training operates by splitting samples into two categories, one is all the false_positives and the other is the union of all the names (minus the guesses).

After 10 epochs I get to this loss, which seems pretty ok:

```
| Adam | epoch: 010 | loss: 0.07699 - acc: 0.9907 | val_loss: 0.37000 - val_acc: 0.8916 -- iter: 3172/3172
```

The thing is, I can't tell if it's memorized the training data or if it's actually learned something.

So, how do I tune this system? Adding and removing layers, changing dimensions, and changing random numbers feels like black magic.

What would be a rational approach to improving (maximizing, really) the accuracy of this detection system? Thanks!

Comment: It is better to play with already tested network architecture like in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been reading the code in the speech_commands and noted that their models are quite different from mine, e.g. no LSTM. I wonder why? Anyway, I am working on incorporating the TF models into my testbed and will evaluate their accuracy and performance. BTW, I noted that these examples use an MFCC component from Tensorflow, which means I can drop my dependency on librosa, that's an advantage already.